# Build failed with an exception( flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build

when I try to build the program this failure happen?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\Desktop\MobileApp\fidt\android\build.gradle' line: ?
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> Could not get unknown property 'flutter' for object of type org.gradle.internal.extensibility.DefaultExtraPropertiesExtension.

```
build.gradle

buildscript {
    ext {
        ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion
    }
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

i try to change the android gradle and gradle version
but nothing change

Comment: Can you add full exception?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the first line `build.gradle`

[image]

It resolved my issue.

[image]

Comment: didn't solve the problem

Comment: Can you share your complete exception?